# Owl Carousel Slides all render as one stacked block

Tags: jquery, html, css, owl-carousel

Below is my code for a very basic owl carousel. It is meant to have only one image / slide displaying at any one time, but at the minute I am ending up with a stack of all these images in a single slide. I'm sure I must be doing something very obviously wrong.

```
<ul class="showcasecarousel">

    <li class="item"><img src="img/trackback.png" alt="Some text here"></li>
    <li class="item"><img src="img/trackback.png" alt="Some text here"></li>
    <li class="item"><img src="img/trackback.png" alt="Some text here"></li>

</ul>
```

The JavaScript at the bottom of my HTML file is:

```
$('.showcasecarousel').owlCarousel({
   navigation : false, // Show next and prev buttons
   slideSpeed : 300,
   paginationSpeed : 400,
   singleItem: true,
   loop: true,
});
```

And finally, the CSS I have is:

```
.showcasecarousel .item img{
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Both of the CSS and JS files for Owl Carousel and JavaScript have been properly included too - there are other carousels on the same page and they work fine. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When I inspect it on Chrome, they show up as three different divs but are all of the class "owl-item active" - I imagine there should only be one of this class?

Comment: Could you create a jsfiddle?

Comment: I tried to but I wasn't sure how to load OwlCarousel into it

Comment: Any console errors? remove custom CSS (owl does the job)?

Comment: No console errors, and I just removed all of the custom CSS, didn't fix it either

Comment: Perhaps because you wrapped the list items in divs? `ul` can only have `li` as childs.

Comment: That was a last gasp attempt to fix it before I brought it here - it still didn't work haha! I should remove those now actually.

Comment: From the docs: 'Class "owl-carousel" is mandatory to apply proper styles that come from owl.carousel.css file'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the `items` property. in your javascript insert `items: 1,`. Also why is twitter-bootstrap tagged? Have another look at the owl-carousel documentation: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/demos.html

Comment: `items:1` should be included by the `singleitem: true` line, unfortunately. Sorry, I mistagged - fixed now!